# Android studio Gradle Build Running stuck, desktop app, How do i get it to complete the build?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, libgdx, build.gradle, desktop-application

I have created a default project with libGDX and imported it in android studio
i have not even touched the code and it is the default template that libGDX creates.

When i run it on android virtual device it works fine and displays a red screen and badlogic logo.

Problem occurs when i try to run the same thing as a desktop app.

when i click run, the app runs and displays the red background with badlogic logo **however, Gradle Build Running is displayed in android studio status bar and it never completes, meanwhile the app is running [image of what im talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xygof.jpg)**

Then when i stop the app i get the following error

> Execution failed for task ':desktop:DesktopLauncher.main()'.
> Build cancelled while executing task ':desktop:DesktopLauncher.main()'

**How do i get gradle to finish the build for desktop app? if i run it on android emulator the build completes successfully in less than 10 seconds**

More details:

in the edit configurations i have set the
main class to: com.packagename.desktop.DesktopLauncher

working directory:  pointing to android assets

Other than that i haven't touched anything else. I've been searching the internet for the answer for hours and haven't found my issue. Thanks in advance for any clues to what is causing this. All the best :)